# Ubuntu Server. Не могу получить доступ Django

Tags: ubuntu, django

Всем добрый день.
Есть роутер Eltex где я настроил проброс порта с 80 на 8000 (порт по умолчанию для джанго) на нужный мне комп (их два: главный имеет адрес 192.168.1.5), который имеет адрес 192.168.1.10 во внутренней сети. Цель такая - открыть публичный доступ к джанго извне.
Когда стартую сервер джанго то в netstat появляется

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:8000          *:*                     LISTEN
```

С главного компа пытаюсь открыть джанго - 192.168.1.10:8000, но получаю connection refused. В iptables прописывал открытие портов, но бесполезно.
Если запускаю джанго на 80 порту, то могу по локалке попасть на него (192.168.1.10), а извне никак не удается(
Что делаю не так?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`192.168.1.10:8000` вы пытаетесь этот адресс открыть а django слушает `localhost:8000`
т.е. `127.0.0.1.`
Попробуйте запустить сервер на публичный ip а не на локальную петлю т.е.

```
./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.10:8000
```

или же на адресс 0.0.0.0

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! :) ./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.10:8000 - помогло